# What is the best way to enable content authors to add images with captions in Expression Engine

Tags: content-management-system, ckeditor, expressionengine

There's a module to do this in Drupal land, but I've been frustrated with the hacks that've been necessary in Wygwam. What is the best way to go about implementing this in such a way that you don't need to totally override the default image handling in ChannelImages/Wygwam?

Comment: There's a 100 and 1 ways to implement imagery for content, so could you be more specific about the end requirement - does it need to be in situ anywhere within the wygwam content text? Is it that some authors can edit text but can't add/edit imagery? Or is that you want all editors to be able to do, but haven't set the user group rights to upload imagery?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that Wygwam is very inflexible in handling comments. There are broadly-used options for WordPress and Drupal, but relatively little for EE. My conclusion at this point is that EE is, for a litany of reasons, second-class for a publishing website. I was hoping there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Assets is a good suggestion, but I believe Devdemon's channel images might be a better fit for the workflow you're suggesting.
http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/

Clients can add (and see) a caption and more and it's fully integrated with Wygwam and other editors. Devdemon's support is also excellent.

Comment: Yes, we use Channel Images currently. Does Channel Images provide some method to see an images caption in content?

Comment: You mean inside the wysiwyg editor? Don't think so. But if your css stylesheet has styles for these your client should be confident that they're there and rendering as the designer intended. Check the example code on devdemon's site: http://www.devdemon.com/docs/channel_images/tags/images_static.html#example

Answer (score 0):

The Assets module from Pixel & Tonic allows you to double-click on the image (or any other file) and add metadata. You then have access to the metadata in your templates.

Check the screenshot: http://pixelandtonic.com/assets

You can also add metadata using the native File Manager. Click the edit icon from the File Manager and you'll see a few fields. You can use the File Entries tag to access it.

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/file/file_tag.html

Comment: Right, the problem here is that writers can't actually see the caption when they add the photo in Wygwam. Drupal seems to be on this with the Spark project, their adoption of the Aloha Editor and it's capability to display static and dynamic content within the contenteditable field. I was hoping I'd  missed some slick solutions for captions in the EE world, but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use Matrix with one column for the image, one column for the caption, and if a link is needed another column for the link. This of course works best if the image is in a fixed location within your template.

Answer (score 0):

On possible way to accomplish this that I have used is to run some jQuery that looks for images within a certain area, and if they have alt attributes, rewrite the image tag within a  tag with a  tag inside.

so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#page-content > .wrapper img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('alt') !== undefined && $(this).attr('alt').length > 0){
        if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('content-image')){
            $(this).replaceWith("<figure class='content-image "+$(this).attr('class')+"'>"+$($('<div></div>').html($(this).clone().attr('class',''))).html()+"<figcaption>"+$(this).attr('alt')+"</figcaption></figure>");
        }
    }
});
});
```

will do just that. It's looking within a #page-content div for img tags with alt attributes. And then rewriting it as

```
<figure><img src='....' .... /><figcaption>This is the text that was in the alt attribute</figcaption></figure>
```

Soooo, that kinda works. The only caveat is that you had better not use any double-quotes within your alt text, or it will break thangs. Not the cleanest of solutions, but a solution, nonetheless.